# Retain cycles when using ARC and blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

From my understanding when an object method receives a block as a completion argument I can send "self" in the block:

```
[object doMethodWithCompletion:^{
  [self doSomethingWhenThisMethodCompletes]
}];
```

but if this object "retains" the block (saves it for future use) I should send a "weak" copy of myself:

```
__weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
object.savedBlock = ^{
  [weakSelf doSomethingWhenThisBlockIsCalledFromWithinObject];
};
```

but I have also seen variants such as:

```
__weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
object.savedBlock = ^{
  __typeof__(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
  [strongSelf doSomethingWhenThisBlockIsCalledFromWithinObject];
};
```

and I am not clear on why/when to do this last variant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a strong reference inside the block makes sure that if the block runs, the object is not deallocated halfway through the block, which could lead to unexpected, hard to debug behaviour.

```
typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[anObject retainThisBlock:^{
    [weakSelf foo];
    // another thread could release the object pointed to by weakSelf
    [weakSelf bar];
}];
```

Now `[weakSelf foo]` would run, but `[weakSelf bar]` wouldn't because weakSelf is now `nil`. If you create a strong reference inside the block, the object can't be released until the block returns.